# React noob question trying to figure out how to use .forEach or .includes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

task is to go through an array and check if there is a string that the user inputs into the form by using forEach or .includes

so basically just trying to filter out the array if possible if someone can show me a .map .foreach and .includes answer it would help

here is my code

```
import './App.css';
import wedding from "./images/wedding.jpg"
import React, { useState } from 'react'


function App() {
const [userInput , setUserInput] = useState("")

const guestList = ["Angela","Jack","Pan","James","Lara","Jason"]

function submitHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  if(guestList.includes(e)){
    console.log( `${e} is on the guest list`)
  }
else{
  console.log('you are not on the guest list ')
}

}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Are you on the guest list?</h1>
    <img className="wedding" src={wedding} alt="wedding" />
    <form onSubmit={submitHandle}>
    <label>Type your name we will check if it is on the guestlist!</label>
    <input type="text" value={userInput} onChange={e => setUserInput(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
import './App.css';
import wedding from "./logo.svg"
import React, { useState } from 'react'


export default function App() {
const [userInput , setUserInput] = useState("")

const guestList = ["Angela","Jack","Pan","James","Lara","Jason"]

function submitHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  if(guestList.includes(userInput)){
    console.log( `${userInput} is on the guest list`)
  }
else{
  console.log('you are not on the guest list ')
}

}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Are you on the guest list?</h1>
    <img className="wedding" src={wedding} alt="wedding" />
    <form onSubmit={submitHandle}>
    <label>Type your name we will check if it is on the guestlist!</label>
    <input type="text" value={userInput} onChange={e => setUserInput(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your submitHandle function you need to check the state userInput for the input value, not the event.